# why we use Asp.net WebApi while doing CRUD operations?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

we can do CRUD operations using Entity framework but we can also do same CRUD operations using entity framework & Web Api.But why we need to  use WEebApi.please give a real time Example..Try to tell  answer without using it is light weight or to make restful services..
please differentiate between CRUD operation using entity framework and EF + webApi..what happen when we use one another.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework is an object-relational mapper (O/RM) that helps with data access from DB.
It can be used to perform CRUD operations, execute Stored procedures, query views etc.

Web API is similar to web service. It is primarily used to communicate over HTTP which entity framework cannot do. Web API can receive requests over Http and call Data Access Layer (EF) to perform data access operations.

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework is an ORM. Assume you build a web application which functions on its own, has a UI and saves stuff to the db. In a simple scenario like this there is no point in trying to complicate things by adding an API into the mix, so your ORM is more than enough.

Now, imagine you have 2 applications, a web one and also a mobile app. They both take data and they both need to save that data to a database.

How do you achieve that without duplicating the work? This is when an API becomes needed. 
You build an API, hide the database operations behind it and now both your web app and mobile can talk to one common layer and use the same data. This a very common scenario, if multiple apps need to share the same data.

There are of course other use cases, sometimes an entire business is focusing on providing data to clients and don't want to worry too much about how they're going to do it. They would provide an API, document the standards, secure their API and let clients use it as they need to.